# Playing sound when new high score is met in snake game. How do I only run that specific line in the function once?

Tags: c#

```
if (Settings.Score > highScore.oldHighSocre)
{
    highScore.newHighScore = Settings.Score;
    highScore.oldHighSocre = highScore.newHighScore;

    label5.Text = highScore.newHighScore.ToString();

    highScore.congrats.Play(); 
}
```

I want to play the sound only the first time the new highscore is met. How can i run the code once in the given function

Comment: NewHighScore flag?

Comment: You know how to check if the current score is higher than the highest score but you don't know how to check if the new high score sound was played?

Comment: Above code is buggy. First you update newHighScore with Score, then oldHighScore with newHighScore. So everything is Score ...

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is that you need some sort of a memory to remember whether the sound has already been played or not. The usual way to accomplish this is to use a `bool`ean flag since it is a YES or NO (boolean) decission.

Declare a `bool` variable outside of your method.

```
bool alreadyPlayed = false;
```

inside your method check the variable ans set it to `true` once you played that sound

```
private void YourMethod()
{
    if(!alreadyPlayed)
    {
        highScore.congrats.Play(); 
        alreadyPlayed = true;
    }
...
```

The next time this part will be skipped and you will never have to hear it again. Unless you reset `alreadyPlayed` back to `false`.

Comment: This kinda worked. But now it plays every time the game starts, I set it to false in the startGame function so it restarts in the "next round"

Comment: I don't really get this. Is this a problem now? if you don't want to hear it again, don't reset it to false again. Or is it part of an object that gets recreated each round anew ?=!

Comment: The purpose of playing the sound is to indicate that there is a new highscore, so it needs to be played every round. However, it plays as soon as the game starts, so when the actual highscore is met no sound is played

Comment: @user7061197 I'd guess you are running that code in a wrong place then. Why does it have to be checked on startup?

Comment: It actually doesn't. Where would you first check it?

Comment: "Where would you first check it?"  there where you evaluate `Settings.Score`. Basically after the score has changed.